# how to find dot product of two lists using only recursion(no loops or list comprehensions) in python?

Tags: python

1. Need to find dot product of two lists
2. Cannot use for, while etc loops
3. cannot use list comprehensions
4. solution has to be purely in recursion terms

   ```
   def mult(n, m): 
       if n == 0: 
           return 0 
       elif n == 1: 
           return m 
       elif n < 0: 
           return -mult(-n, m) 
       else: return m + mult(n-1, m) 

   def dot(l1,l2): 
       if len(l1)==len(l2) and len(l2)!=0: 
           return sum([mult(l1[n],l2[n]) for n in range(len(l2))]) 
       else: return 0 

   print(dot([1,2],[3,4]))
   ```

Comment: Could you show us some code you've tried?

Comment: Take the head of both lists, find the product, then add that to the dot product of the tails.

Comment: def mult(n, m):
   if n == 0:
      return 0
   elif n == 1:
      return m
   elif n < 0:
    return -mult(-n, m)
   else:
      return m + mult(n-1, m)

      
def dot(l1,l2):
        if len(l1)==len(l2) and len(l2)!=0:
            return sum([mult(l1[n],l2[n]) for n in range(len(l2))])
        else:
            return 0
print(dot([1,2],[3,4]))

Comment: Please make sure to include sample code and sample desired output , in its current format this does not make for a good question, and will likely delay the ability for others to assist.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52347018/edit) your question to add code there.

Comment: @Ausitn, I added the code, its submitted for review

Answer (score 1):

If the vectors are lists, the dot product is

```
v1[0]*v2[0] + v1[1]*v2[1] + v1[2]*v2[2] + ...
```

So if a single recursion step can multiply the first pair of numbers and then add it to the same function called on the remainder of the lists until the lists are empty. We treat the process as:

```
(v1[0]*v2[0] + (v1[1]*v2[1] + (v1[2]*v2[2] + ... + 0) ... )))
```

For example,

```
def dot(v1, v2):
    if not v1:
        # We're done: nothing to add on
        return 0
    # Multiply the first numbers and add to the dot product of the rest
    return v1[0] * v2[0] + dot(v1[1:],v2[1:])

dp = dot([1,2,3],[4,1,8])
print(dp)

30  # =(1*4 + (2*1 + (3*8)))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def dotproduct(x,y):
    'returns the dot product of two vectors'
    if len(x) and len(y) == 1:
        return x[0]*y[0]
    else:
        n = x[0]
        m = y[0]
        x.remove(n)
        y.remove(m)
        return dotproduct(x,y) + n*m
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76238278/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).